# Unexpected behaviour by proc append

Tags: sas, append

I execute the following code:

```
data temp1;
  set sashelp.class;
  table=1;
run;

data temp2;
  set sashelp.class;
  table=2;
run;

proc append base=temp1(drop=sex) data=temp2 force;
run;
```

I thought that `sex` will be dropped from temp1. So `sex` is missing it will be also dropped from temp2 and result set does not contain column `sex`.

However I am irritated by the real result:
[image]

Why is `sex` for `table=1` filled and for `table=2` empty?

Comment: BASE is not altered in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @data *null* mentions, when using proc append the base dataset is not altered.  This is the primary reason to use proc append - it does not require a 'pass' of the base dataset, and just *appends* the data to the end.

In this (rather special) case, the `sex` variable is considered dropped and so it is not written/ visible for the subsequent append.

Also (thanks again @data *null*) there was a clue here from the WARNING in the log.  As a matter of best practice, one should always aim to write code that runs without ERRORs or WARNINGs..

Comment: WARNING: Variable Sex was not found on BASE file. The variable will not be added to the BASE file.  This warning explains what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.